# HTML5 and peripherals

Tags: html, forms, peripherals

I have done a search on this and I think I actually came away more confused.  We are looking for a solution where we supply a card swiper for a mobile device. Just a swiper, we do not need a gateway solution.

We want to be able to have someone swipe a card and then have the card information auto-populate in an HTML form.

Simple question:  Is this possible and if so, any suggestions on how to go about it?  I cant seem to find much out there on this.

Thanks,

Comment: This looks promising: http://garetjax.info/blog/articles/2010/01/magnetic-card-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you need a activex or similar installed in the brower, to get hold of the PC's comport. I used Silverlight for the same reason. Wanted the input from a barcode scanner to act different that the operators input.

Hope it helps :)